# Reach js-conflux-sdk git repo cannot be read when building from CI Docker container

Tags: docker, github-actions, yarnpkg, reach

The step in my Docker file which reads `RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile` is failing with the following error text when executed in a .github action.

It reads as though there's a problem running `git ls remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/reach-sh/js-conflux-sdk.git` which further seems to indicate that 'ssh: not found'

'ssh' is definitely present within the build environment, and the `reach-sh/js-conflux-sdk` repo is not private. I cannot reproduce this on my local machine.  What am I missing?

```
#10 [builder 6/7] RUN yarn install
#10 sha256:0241e5ad2b01044255a03052e8f2a2540c5fb45a447a1b93c55b90ed86436440
#10 10.84 yarn install v1.22.17
#10 11.81 [1/4] Resolving packages...
#10 12.75 [2/4] Fetching packages...
#10 13.13 error Command failed.
#10 13.13 Exit code: 128
#10 13.13 Command: git
#10 13.13 Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/reach-sh/js-conflux-sdk.git
#10 13.13 Directory: /apps/launchpad-api
#10 13.13 Output:
#10 13.13 "ssh" -oBatchMode=yes: line 1: ssh: not found
#10 13.13 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
#10 13.13 
#10 13.13 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
#10 13.13 and the repository exists.
#10 13.13 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
#10 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn install]: exit code: 128
------
 > [builder 6/7] RUN yarn install:
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn install]: exit code: 128
```

I've attempted explicitly installing ssh into the build container which reported that ssh was already installed.

I've checked that `git ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/reach-sh/js-conflux-sdk.git` can be run from my local machine without any special permissions.

I've tried to delete and rebuild my yarn.lock file which didn't do anything at all differently.

Comment: I experienced the same issue when building my NextJS app that imports the Reach client library in my CI on AWS Amplify.

Answer (score 1):

I reported [this issue](https://github.com/reach-sh/reach-lang/issues/714) on the Reach GitHub repository.

This happens because the version of `js-conflux-sdk` - one of the `stdlib` dependencies - is specified as `js-conflux-sdk@git+https://github.com/reach-sh/js-conflux-sdk.git#v1_6_0_blockNumber`.

This makes the build script to clone the repo using SSH `ssh://git@github.com/reach-sh/js-conflux-sdk.git`, which fails on a CI container because of missing SSH keys.

This problem can be temporarily solved replacing `ssh://git@` with `https://` in `package-lock.json` and running `npm ci` or `yarn install --frozen-lockfile`.

I suppose the source of this issue is [this line](https://github.com/reach-sh/js-reach-stdlib/blob/3cbdd65457670463ca4d283f65db12096605f533/package.json#L46).

The version is specified referencing the github repository, which gets resolved with `ssh://git@` when generating `package-lock-json`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for that response! I ended up resolving the issue by not removing the lockfile and running with a simple `yarn install` but I believe have a better understanding of the issue now after your comment.